# Reading array values from return method

Tags: java, android, arrays

How can I safely read both of my array values from another class method without the nullexception warning coming up.I am getting both values orreclty just worried about the "Array access x[0] may produce NPE " warning without using intents

```
 public Class ImageUtility{

 public static String[] savePicture(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {

  ......

   String[] arr = new String[2];
        arr[0] = img_name;
        arr[1] = img_path;

        return arr;
   }



public Class Others{

 public void Test(){
 String[] x = ImageUtility.savePicture(getActivity(), bitmap);
 value_one= x[0]; //nullexception warning is here
 value_two= x[1];

  }
```

Comment: check the `length` of `x`, if it is 0, there is something wrong with your method.

Comment: why would `value_one= x[0];` give you a NPE even if `x[0]` is null?

Comment: how  you get img_name  and img_path?

Comment: @Cgx they are strings am collecting nothing to worry about there..both are not null

Comment: @Aeonia maybe it's a AsyncTask when you savePicture,so when you call test(), the savePicture not finished yet

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am not getting an NPE just a warning from the compiler "Array access x[0] may produce NPE "

Comment: restart your IDE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
 public void Test(){
   try{
     String[] x = ImageUtility.savePicture(getActivity(), bitmap);
     if(x != null && x.Length >= 1){
       value_one= x[0]; 
       value_two= x[1];
     }
   }catch(NullPointerException e){
     //print log
   }
 }
```

Comment: am now getting the warning Deference of x may produce NPE right at x.length

Comment: if(x != null && x.Length >= 1){

Comment: Thanks..warning is no longer present